# Xcode quit unexpectedly while using the dsc_extractor.bundle plugin

Tags: xcode, macos, ios7, iphone-5

When I attach my new iPhone 5s to my Mac, Xcode crashes with this error:

**Xcode quit unexpectedly while using the dsc_extractor.bundle plugin**

This happens while Xcode is processing symbols from the device.

It all works fine on my iPad4 which is running IOS 6.1.3.

I updated MacOS to Maverick, I reinstalled Xcode and I still have the same error.

My current Xcode version is 5.0.2 (3335.32), iPhone IOS is 7.0.4 (11B554a).

Comment: Sounds like you should open a bug report with Apple.

Comment: I did but no answer yet and all I can google up is my question.

Comment: Post the radar number in your question, so people with a similar problem can duplicate it and make it a higher priority at Apple. I also suggest posting this question on the Apple developer forums, where Apple engineers often post.

Comment: Have you tried using different USB ports?

Answer (score 11):

For me it worked out when I delete the `"~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/(iOS Version of the device)"` folder. It is recreated next time, when the device is connected to the Mac and Xcode is running.

A previous restore of the iPhone 5S did not help and I had no problems to connect the device to another Mac. So it seems to be an issue only on the Mac and not on the device.

Comment: GOD! I must comment this answer...This issue drove me crazy for two days. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me as well. Should be accepted as answer.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks dude. I also deleted ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproject-xxxx which helped my other issue with the build.

Answer (score 0):

I use a 5S both with a MBPro/Mavericks and regular MB/Snow Leopard; it works fine. Something is messed up on your system, I suspect. Any 3rd party extensions? Try logging out, and logging back in with the shift key down (prevents extensions from loading).

Answer (score -2):

I formatted hard drive and re installed Maverick and that did the trick.